# conditional format based on two table column values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

The 1st picture below shows something close to what I want to do; apply a red format IF the following two conditions are true:

1. The [Symbol] column value = "CASH" (column address $B5:$B204)
2. The date of the [SP Fill Column] is less than Today (column address $CH5:$CH204)

I am trying to do this with two rules applied to the entire CH column as shown below, without success. It seems like I should be apply to just apply the rule to the 3 cells relative to the CASH symbols, but sorting and filtering changes the values.

What is a good way to do this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: use AND(): `=AND($B5="CASH",$CH5<TODAY())`

Comment: yeah, perfect! want to make this an answer so I can close out the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND():

```
=AND($B5="CASH",$CH5<TODAY())
```